# Testing data from web hook in Home Assistant

Tags: jinja2, home-assistant, home-automation

I receive numerous webhooks from several vehicle GPS trackers in Home Assistant.  The web hook is defined in a template in the config file as a sensor with numerous attributes; that all works.  One of the data items in the json string is a vehicle ID.  I would like to define another sensor for a specific vehicle and then trigger some automations based on data for that vehicle.  What is the best way to do that?